# AWS Amplify permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to access an API gateway endpoint using AWS amplify but I keep getting permission denied.

However, I can directly access the api using the api gateway url directly.
Any idea as to what the reason could be?

Here is my setup
CloudFront -> ReactApp -> API Gateway

I have mandatorySignIn: false in Amplify configure

Comment: Use sudo to execute your commands. You do not have admin privileges

Comment: What do you mean sudo? This is from javascript app

Comment: If it’s js try using chmod commands. You need to access the folder as a super user

Comment: Updating the question with any or all of these items would be helpful: 1) 
 API Gateway configuration (Authorizer being used? API key? CORS enabled?)  2)  Amplify code - configuration and API call  3) Actual contents of the permission denied error.  Is it a 403? Are there CORS type errors in the console?  Is there an error message beyond "permission denied"?  What do the response headers look like?

Comment: Just figured out something. It has got to do with me not creating a root object.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly? Can you post it? Is it CORS related?

Comment: Sorry it was not CORS. I was missing the root object for cloudfront.